# I need more light on the homework policy

Tags: discussion, scope, questions, homework-and-exercises

Please, I need to know what is wrong if one posts their homework here and it is well formatted?

The actual thing is they might have tried solving before coming here in the case where they didn't have another place to go seek for some 'thinking' or solution before the real homework correction day reaches.

People may not sometimes always post such because they want everything to be solved for them... I personally don't post homework here though given I don't even participate around that often.

I don't know if you can take a look into that?

Comment: But I still don't understand why the downvotes too... Is this question not going to be useful for those who post their homework here then?

Comment: [Voting is different on meta](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to @Chair:

It will not really make sense for anybody to be scrounging through the answers to someone else's homework in order to find out how some aspect of physics works.

The only people who can be helped in this case are the people who have the exact same homework problem... I think I now get the point, anyway!

Comment: @Chair, did I make the answering any simple, please?

Comment: Yeah, this is pretty much what I was saying in the comments. There are several meta posts regarding this; I'll mention them if I get around to writing an answer (unlikely, since this suns up my point well).